# Convert string to coordinates in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string, location, coordinates

I have some coordinates that I converted into a string with the following code:

```
 label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%f",
               venue.location.coordinate.latitude,
               venue.location.coordinate.longitude];
```

However, I now want to convert the string back to the lat and long coordinates. How do I do this?

Comment: It would help A LOT if you put a delimiter between the two numbers.

Comment: Almost certainly easier to re-access the original source of the information than fiddle with string parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, because your code did not provide a separator between the values. Therefore, you wouldn't be able to figure out if a string

```
12.3456.78
```

has been one of the pairs below:

```
12.3 456.78
12.34 56.78
12.345 6.78
12.3456 .78
```

In order to make the conversion reversible, use `@"%f %f"` format (with a space). Now you could use many different ways of parsing the data back from the string - for example, `sscanf`:

```
float lat, lon;
sscanf([label3.text UTF8String], "%f %f", &lat, &lon);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much, spent a couple of hours trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

if you separate your floats with a delimiter, like this:

```
label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f;%f",
               venue.location.coordinate.latitude,
               venue.location.coordinate.longitude];
```

Then

```
CGPoint yourPoint=CGPointMake((NSString*)([[label3.text componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] 
firstObject]).floatValue,(NSString*)([[label3.text componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] lastObject]).floatValue)
//yourPoint.x is latitude, yourPoint.y is longitude
```

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D would be a more appropriate struct than CGPoint.  In fact, the OP should be keeping the coordinates in such a struct to begin with rather than scraping from a string.